# Crypto key generation

Tags: java

What is the easiest way to generate encoded hex 32 string from input string and some number(For example (for start) I could use not a number but current date)?
 In c# I have used PasswordDeriveBytes for such kind of issues. Is there some analog in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

> javax.crypto.Cipher

[some examples](https://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleCrypt.html)